# /usr/bin/docker-current: Error parsing reference .. invalid reference format

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, haproxy

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker images
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
haproxy             latest              e4e1b2695b0b        10 days ago         69.5 MB
[root@localhost ~]# docker run ‐it ‐d ‐p 4001:8888 ‐p 4002:3306 ‐v /home/soft/haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy ‐‐name h1 ‐‐privileged ‐‐net=net1 ‐‐ip 172.18.0.7 haproxy
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error parsing reference: "‐it" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.

[root@localhost ~]# docker run ‐it ‐d ‐p 4001:8888 ‐p 4002:3306 ‐v /home/soft/haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy ‐‐name h1 ‐‐privileged ‐‐net=net1 ‐‐ip 172.18.0.7 e4e1b2695b0b
/usr/bin/docker-current: Error parsing reference: "‐it" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format.
See '/usr/bin/docker-current run --help'.
```

I don't understand what's the problem.
is any invalid command? 
and if just "docker run -it haproxy bash" is fine

and use image id or haproxy:latest also has this error

any guys konw the reason, thx

Comment: `_` is not `-`.

Comment: Compare the `‐it` in your command and `--help` in the error message; you somehow typed odd-looking hyphens, consistently.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you might have copy-pasted this code from somewhere which had converted the 
regular ASCII `-` into a Unicode hyphen (https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm) they look deceptively similar, but Docker will not work with the latter.